# color rows in Excel file iteratively

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, writer

I want to color the whole row of an Excel file if the first string in the first two columns is the same.
The two columns contain the address, so normally it should be numbers.

My code for this is

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame("Data")[0]
nr = 1
while nr < len(df1['address 1']):
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Path)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame("Data")[nr]
        dfC1 = df2['address 1'].split()
        dfC2 = df2['address 2'].split()

        def highlight_cells():
            return ['background-color: yellow']

        if dfC1[0].__contains__(dfC2[0]):
            df2.style.apply(highlight_cells)
        else: pass
        df1 = df1.append(df2)
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
        writer.save()

        nr+=1
```

it's embedded in a try. That's why I don't have an error message.
I was able to isolate the if condition and when I run it I had the desired True and False statements.
But I don't know how to get the rows in the excel file colored.

Does anybody know how I do this?
Thanks

Comment: To get the error message, you can print it in the except block. Something like `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: The result was 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'. Because of this I changed      ```dfC1 = df2['address 1'].split()                                                                                      dfC2 = df2['address 2'].split()``` to ```dfC1 = df2['address 1'][nr].split()                                                                                      dfC2 = df2['address 2'][nr].split()``` This resulted in the error message "1". What does mean "1"?

Comment: Do you have more print statements in your code? Maybe the print is from an other statement?

Comment: no, there are no other prints...

Comment: Actually it prints the "nr". when I use ``` nr += 1 ``` it prints all nr values until it is at the last row. So why does this happen when I want the exception?